# Is there a device to give my computer gpio pins through a usb port?

Tags: usb, gpio

I am trying to control LEDs through my computer. Is there a device that I can plug into a USB port that would give me pins that I can control through code(preferably python) on my computer? Something similar to a raspberry pi or Arduino. The reason I want to control it through my computer and not a microcontroller is because I have data on the computer is used to determine the color of the LEDs. My current setup controls the LEDs with a raspberry pi over wifi but it is not as responsive as I feel it could be and makes the LEDs kind of a pain to use. If a device like this exists, it would make everything much more simple and professional looking. Thanks.

Comment: Just google, USB RGB controller.

Comment: These seem to be designed for specific led strips or lights. I have single led bulbs so in order to control multiple I need a set of 3 pins for each.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into legacy PC parallel printer ports, they have multiple pins that can be controlled by software.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the [Adafruit FT232H Breakout](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2264), which can be connected via USB to control GPIO pins.